# Is there any HW wallet that works with Electrum without the need for installing anything?

Tags: electrum, ledger-hardware-wallet

Ledger Nano S Plus needs to you download Ledger Live and install the Bitcoin application in order to be able to open it with Electrum.

Is there any HW wallet that can be opened with Electrum directly, without the need for intermediate steps such as the above one? (steps that involve to connect the HW wallet to the internet and download/install stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question. unfortunately most hardware wallets are going to need an intermediate initial one time step like you described above to begin interfacing with the software wallet.

Even coldcard exports a skeleton wallet file to software wallets like electrum, or sparrow wallet. This enables the software wallet to know what it is looking at.

Functionally though, skeleton wallets can be much more secure to use than something like installing the ledger bitcoin wallet app on the ledger via USB.

Trezor also has an initial one time setup step, where you download their bridge app on your desktop so your device can talk to it's web app.

With all that said, I would try to aim for the more sovereign open source bitcoin only options as a guiding principle to your wallet journey.

Convenience can be the enemy of security.